# How to resize an uploded image before using it in an imagecreatefromjpeg function?

Tags: php

I have a code that allows file upload and some text input. It uses the uploaded file in an imagacreatefromjepg and imagecopymerge. I want to resize the uploaded file to a definite size which is 255x175. how can i make it? Here is what is have:

```
        $now = time();
    while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']))
    {
        $now++;
    }

    // now let's move the file to its final and allocate it with the new filename
    @move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename)
        or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm);

    $upload = $uploadFilename;
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("bg.jpg");
    $img2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $font = 'arialbi.ttf';
    $font2 = 'ariali.ttf';

    imagettftext($im, 24, 0, 50, 280, $black, $font, $title);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 320, 362, $black, $font, $namehere);

    imagecopymerge($im, $img2, 30, 350, 0, 0, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2), 100);

    $date_created = date("YmdHis");//get date created
    $img_name = "-img_entry.jpg"; //the file name of the generated image
    $img_newname = $date_created . $img_name; //datecreated+name
    $img_dir =dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ."/". $img_newname; //the location to save the image 
    imagejpeg($im, $img_dir , 80); //function to save the image with the name and quality

    $newpath = "/home3/site/public_html/mainfolder/image_entry/";//path to another folder
    $newdir = $newpath.$img_newname;
    copy ($img_dir, $newdir); //copy to new folder

    imagedestroy($im);
```

Hope you can help me fix this. I have raed the posts [Resize image before uploading PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786968/resize-image-before-uploading-php) and [Php resize width fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273051/php-resize-width-fix). But I dont know how to apply it in my case. Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: why you want to resize before it is uploading?

Comment: in my case i have the file already uploaded before i use it in imagecreatefrom jpeg and imagecopymerge. is there a way i can resize it efore saving it to the server?

Comment: check here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333971/html5-pre-resize-images-before-uploading

Answer (score 0):

just after: `imagecopymerge($im,...` line

```
$mini_width = ...;// calculate desirable width
$mini_height = ...;// calculate desirable height
$mini_img = @ImageCreateTrueColor($mini_width, $mini_height);
imagecopyresampled($mini_img, $img2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $mini_width, $mini_height, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2));
```

next line is `$date_created = date(...`

change `imagejpeg($im, $img_dir , 80);` to:

```
imagejpeg($mini_img, $img_dir , 80);
```

and finally change `imagedestroy($im);` to `imagedestroy($mini_img);`

Actually, you can, but not have to call `imagedestroy()` for all the resource images created above.

Comment: Thank you @Ruben for answering. It's the $img2 that i actually want to resize. It's not the background image but the uploaded one i used in here 'imagecopymerge($im, $img2, 30, 350, 0, 0, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2), 100);'. I have two images in my code. one background and one to place above it. I'm sorry if I confused you. How can i apply your answer with $img2? thanks

Comment: Oh! No problem! It's totally my fault! Thank you! It is fixed.

Comment: thanks again. so how can i call now the resized image so ican exctly use it in `imagecopymerge($im, $img2, 30, 350, 0, 0, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2), 100);`. in your code, the `imagepng($mini_img);` creates the resized image right? thanks again for firther help :)

Comment: Are you ever thinking about eliminate `imagettftext()` because of kerning and outlines? You can just `imagecopymerge()` with transparent high quality png with perfect kerned text block.

Comment: Actually till the `imagepng()/imagejpeg()' you have `$im` -- resource with background, `$img2` - resource with photo over background and `$mini_img` -- minimized final image. You can do anything you want with them. `imagepng()` just flush resource out to the browser and stops execution.

Comment: no it's not the final image i want to resize. it's the image over backegorund that i want to resize. (those are the images uploaded by the user)...the final image doesnot need to be displayed in the browser. it's being saved in my sever. i edited my code above for you to see. im really sorry if my question is confusing. thank for further help